# Why isn't 'debdelta' used by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, debdelta

`debdelta` is a program that allows for delta updates. It means that it will allow to only download the difference between the packages, which will reduce the download size.

To use this program, you install it with `sudo apt-get install debdelta`. Then to update, you do :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo debdelta-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So my question is : why isn't this program used by default in `Ubuntu` ?
 it would be a killer feature.

Comment: This is very interesting! Does it really work? or How does it work?

Comment: I installed it today, and I am waiting for a big update to test.

Comment: You need sha 256 keys for the uncompressed deb. I don't think those are available. The download will be larger too ,(since it is done on uncompressed update even when just partial updates)

Comment: But why do you think this should be in default Ubuntu? Many other programs aren't in default Ubuntu, isn't it?

Comment: Why not @Anwar, it is a great feature, especially that some packages are very heavy, so it will consume a lot of bandwidth to update.

Answer (score 2):

There is two main reason in my point of view:

First of all there is no mirror for delta thus the download speed is too slow and at the same time servers will be under heavy pressure.

Second is, it's more complicated for both client/server side to implement, client machine should invest more power and time to use deltas in contrast of regular updates, in the other hand high speed Internet is available almost in most of the places, so it's more logical to prefer regular updates over delta.

Read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDebdeltaSupport).

Comment: But deltas are useful isn't it? and snap highlights the usability of delta upgrades.

Comment: Sure they are, but not how they're implemented right now, snap is using same idea for another achievement IMO.

Comment: If they could _invent_ snap with delta upgrade possibility, is it too difficult to use delta upgrades for deb packages?

Comment: I'm not really into snap and how they implemented it, so I'm not even sure that it's somehow the same thing.  As I know it downloads the parts you need however those parts will be downloaded completely. The other thing is that delta is already there, we're not going to invent it again.

Comment: @Anwar `yum` uses delta I guess you can read a little bit more about `yum` it might be interesting to you.

Comment: Upvoted the answer. I think the main reason is there aren't many people needing this at the moment. The page was updated in 2011. Nothing happened between these years it seems. And yum doesn't integrate well with Ubuntu's deb packages afaik

Comment: Yeah that's another reason, about the `yum` I meant in general and for investigating how it works not for using with Ubuntu :-) thanks for the up ;)